# Number of iterations with a fixed point problem

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, numerical-calculus

I have a problem with this exercise:
Given the function

$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$
$f\binom{x}{y}=\frac{1}{8}\binom{\ln(1+x^2+y^2)-1}{x^2+y^2}$

and the iteration:

$z_{k+1}=f(z_{k}) \text{ and } z_{0}=\binom{0}{0}$

Let $I := [−1, 1] ×[−1, 1]$ and $z^{*}$ the fixed point.
I have to calculate how many iterations are needed to have an estimated error of

$\left \|z_{k}-z^{*}  \right \|_{\infty}\leq 10^{-3}$

How can I start this problem? Is there for example a formula to solve it?

(IDK if it is important but I have alredy proved that the function converges to a fixed point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

For $k \ge 1$, you have using the Mean Value Theorem, and the fact that $z^* = f(z_*)$

$$\begin{aligned}
\lVert z_{k+1} - z^* \rVert &= \lVert f(z_k) - f(z^*)\rVert\\
&\le M  \lVert z_{k} - z^* \rVert\\
&\le M^{k+1} \lVert z_{0} - z^* \rVert\\
&\le \sqrt 2 M^{k+1}
\end{aligned}$$ where $M = \sup\limits_{x \in I} \lVert J_f(x) \rVert$ and $J_f$ the Jacobian of $f$.

Hence if you bound $M$, you can estimate $k$ such that $\sqrt 2 M^{k+1}  \le 10^{-3}$.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand this last step
$$\begin{aligned}
\
\
&\le M^{k+1} \lVert z_{0} - z^* \rVert\\
&\le 2 \sqrt 2 M^{k+1} \lVert z_{0} - z^* \rVert
\end{aligned}$$
Can you please help me?

Comment: I updated the answer. Just remember that $z_0$ is at the center of the square $I$ and that the diagonal length of a square is $\sqrt 2$ times the length of the side.